# Need to generate dynamically excel file from Sql Select Statement using SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I want to generate dynamically excel file using SSIS package.
I tried like following :

In `data flow task` I have taken `Oledb Source` inside `oledb source editor`
under `connection manager` taken `data access mode = sql command from variable` as my variable is having sql query like below `select cusip,price,company from mytable where date in between @[var1] and @[var2]`

But i failed to use `var1` and `var 2` it is giving me parse error.

created 3 variables inside ssis project

`var1 datatype = datetime value=5/01/2011 8:22:10 AM`

`var2 datatype = datetime value=5/21/2011 8:22:10 AM`

`var3 datatype = datetime value=MY ABOVE SELECT QUERY`
Using above select query I want to generate new excel file every day with filename like `MYFile05222013` `(with yesterdays date)`

`var 3 taken as string and added value into Expression`
But getting parse error :

```
Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Must declare the scalar variable "@".".
```

AND

`The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_DATE" are incompatible for binary operator "+". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.`

Please advice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making var3 a string datatype (not a datetime).  Give it an expression like this:

```
"select cusip,price,company from mytable where date in between " + @[User::var1] + " and " + @[User::var2]
```

Make the var1 and var2 variables string datatypes, also.  Set up var1 and var2  with default values that parse to valid datetime values.

To view the evaluation result of the expression, click [Evaluate Expression in the Expression Builder.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141698%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

For the output file, you will want an Excel Destination.  The destination connection manager will have an expression for the filename.  That expression is where you will build a filename like "MYFile05222013".

Comment: I want to set up @var2 dynamically to previous date how can i do so? please help

Comment: Use [GETDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139875.aspx) in an expression for var2.  You'll need to convert it to a string at some point to build your select query.  Have you fixed the parse error in your Oledb Source yet?

Comment: No I'm getting same error again :
`Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Must declare the scalar variable "@".".

`

Comment: Also Getting error : `
The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_DATE" are incompatible for binary operator "+". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.`

Comment: You have declared the [variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141085.aspx), right?  That's within the rdl, not at the project level.

Comment: Yes, the DT_WSTR / DT_DATE error message means exactly what it says.  I said it was necessary to convert the date to a string.  SSIS is very particular about datatypes.

Comment: Hi Yes i have declare an variable please see image edited question.

Comment: You set it in static string rather than an expression.  Probably best to get rid of var3, and use var1 and var2 in an [OLD DB Source Parametrized SQL Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696.aspx) like "SELECT * FROM Production.Product WHERE Color = ? AND Size = ?"

Comment: Getting Error :
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error".