# how to use variable value inside another variable in SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have 3 variables like following in SSIS package

```
NAME       TYPE    VALUE   
FROMDATE   String  '5/1/2011'     
TODATE     String  Select (FunctionPreviousBusinessDay(),112)
OUTPUT     String  Select companyName , price from Mytable where date in between '+ @[User::FROMDATE] + "and"  + @[User::TODate]'
```

OUTPUT is giving me evaluated expression like :

```
Select companyName , price from Mytable where date in between '5/1/2011' and
Select (FunctionPreviousBusinessDay(),112)
```

Instead of execution of variable `TODATE` directly giving string.

I'm expecting output like following

```
Select companyName , price from Mytable where date in between '5/1/2011' and
'5/22/2011'
```

How can i do this ? please advice ?

Directly paste sql query with `?`
but getting following error   :

```
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error".
```

Comment: This is a follow-on to OP's question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691747/need-to-generate-dynamically-excel-file-from-sql-select-statement-using-ssis/16693028 where the main issue is the use of the SSIS Expression Editor. Also, an [OLE DB data source parametrized SQL statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696.aspx) would work better here.

Comment: Directly paste inside oledb source editor getting error (updated in question) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an additional Execute SQL task with a single row result set.  The task's query would be

```
 Select (FunctionPreviousBusinessDay(),112)
```

And its result would need to be set to @TODATE.